# Swift retrieve Place ID from GoogleMaps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I've got the GPS coordinates of a place and want to query the GoogleMaps SDK for the Place ID in order to get more information about a place.

I looked up the documentation https://developers.google.com/places/place-id. But yet didn't found a way on 'easily' get the Place ID like:

```
let placeId = GMSService.getPlaceIdFromCoordinates(longitude: 02.52324, latitude: 03.5345)
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS documentation for Maps and Places API doesn't list `GMSService`, the only class resembling is is [`GMSServices`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_services) which doesn't have the `getPlaceIdFromCoordinates`.

You can look at the [Place IDs and Details](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details) of the Places API documentation. PlaceID can be retrieved from the `GMSPlace` object.

To actually search for places (whether through text or coordinates) you can try out the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) page of the documentation.